# Convolution of derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, convolution

When transforming nonlinear PDE to its Fourier space, I encounter the following problem:

Consider the equation $u_t=(u^3-u)_{xx}$.
Then, when transforming to Fourier space we get

\begin{equation*}
\hat{u}_t=-k^2(\hat{u^3-u})=-k^2(\hat{u}*\hat{u}*\hat{u}-\hat{u}).
 \end{equation*}

On the other hand, if we represent the equation as $u_t=[(3u^2-1)u_x]_x$ we obtain

\begin{equation*}
\hat{[(3u^2-1)u_x]_x}=ik[\hat{3u^2u_x}-\hat{u_x}]=\cdots =-k^2(3\hat{u}\ast \hat{u}\ast \hat{u}-\hat{u}).
\end{equation*}

Can someone please solve this inconsistency for me? If I derive once more the 3 becomes 9...

Thanks,

Alon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\widehat{u^2\,u_x}=\hat u\ast\hat u\ast(i\,k\,\hat u)\ne i\,k\,\hat u\ast\hat u\ast\hat u.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I've realized that too. BTW, the i can be taken outside the convolution since it is indeed a constant.